# How to compare Timestamp in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, where-clause

I have a table with timestamp column i want to get the values where the timestamp in specific month (for example where the timpestamp between 1 september and 30 septemper) taking in considration if the month is 31 day.
I use this query:

```
SELECT users.username, users.id, count(tahminler.tahmin)as tahmins_no FROM users LEFT JOIN tahminler ON users.id = tahminler.user_id  GROUP BY users.id having count(tahminler.tahmin) > 0
```

Can i add `where timestamp  IN(dates_array)`??

date_array will be the dates of the whole month??

Comment: You should use `BETWEEN` clause, if you want to check an interval. Check out here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT users.username, users.id, count(tahminler.tahmin)as tahmins_no 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN tahminler ON users.id = tahminler.user_id  
where year(timestamp) = 2013 and month(timestamp) = 9
GROUP BY users.id 
having count(tahminler.tahmin) > 0
```

To make it work with indexes you can do

```
SELECT users.username, users.id, count(tahminler.tahmin)as tahmins_no 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN tahminler ON users.id = tahminler.user_id  
where timestamp >= '2013-09-01' and timestamp < '2013-10-01'
GROUP BY users.id 
having count(tahminler.tahmin) > 0
```

Comment: +1 It's not actually clear that it is supposed to be 2013 only but that seems most likely.

Comment: It gives me a Error: Token Mismatch

Comment: @BaselShbeb: That does not sound like a MySQL error message. Maybe your error is somewhere else.

Comment: @BaselShbeb: I added an extra info.

Answer (score 4):

In case of TIMESTAMP

```
YEAR (TIMESTAMP) = 2013 AND MONTH (TIMESTAMP) = 9
```

To include in the same clause

```
DATE_FORMAT(TIMESTAMP,'%Y-%m')='2013-09'
```

For unix time stamp

```
YEAR (FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP)) = 2013 AND MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP))=9
```

To include in the same clause

```
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP),'%Y-%m')='2013-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can just add:

```
WHERE MONTH(timestamp)=9
```

Comment: it gives me Error: token mismatch

Comment: Do you have it before the `GROUP BY` clause?