# filter date from timestamp field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have saved rows in my table with custom timezone.Now I want to retrieve data from those table for just **today**.

So here is what I tried

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$dt = new DateTime();
$today = $dt->format('Y-m-d'); //outputs 2015-12-07
$ok = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` = '$today'" );
```

And my row contains date in timestamp format like `2015-12-07 22:42:02`

But I get empty result.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `outputs` function?  I assume this is a function you have written yourself.

Comment: @br3nt : its just mysqli_query , nothing wrong in script...I ran the query directly in phpmyadmin..its returning empty results.

Comment: Ok.  Is the date column definitely a date data type or is it a datetime/timestamp?

Comment: @Vishnu can you try my answer?

Comment: well I tried somehting like this and it works $date = $dt->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00";  and `date` > $date ... some one answer it so i will accept.

Comment: You can answer it yourself

Comment: ***@Vishnu***: What is the output when tried with `... where year( date_field ) = 2015 and month( date_field ) = 12`  ???

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ok = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()" );
```

to convert time according to timezone: [ConvertTimeZone](https://blog.mozilla.org/it/2012/11/16/converting-timezone-specific-times-in-mysql/)

Comment: if possible then also change your column name `date` to other, because `date` is reserved keyword of `MySQL`

Comment: As you see my quesition , i am using los angeles time zone..If i use curdate it will use server timezone

Comment: @Vishnu just check this link, may be it will help: https://blog.mozilla.org/it/2012/11/16/converting-timezone-specific-times-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You should convert date to timestamp before passing it to mysql:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); 
$dt = new DateTime();
$today = $dt->format('Y-m-d'); //outputs 2015-12-07

$ok = outputs("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')= $today" );
```

Comment: not working, I have mentioned that sql clumn value looks like 2015-12-07 22:42:02

Comment: You mentioned before that your column timestamp, but if your column like you mentioned you can use NOW() mysql function which return current date time for now.

Comment: yes also I mentioned I use custom tiemzone...now() will use server timezone

Answer (score 0):

if  $today='2015-12-07 22:42:02'; your query will give the result.

```
$today='2015-12-07 22:42:02';
$ok = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` = '$today'" );
```

else  do pass the today date and next date and retrieve the value as given

```
$today='2015-12-07';
$next='2015-12-08';
$ok = mysqli_query($sqli,"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date` >= '$today' and `date` <= '$next'  " );
```

for more details refer this [Oracle SQL : timestamps in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855378/oracle-sql-timestamps-in-where-clause)  [How to compare Timestamp in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917871/how-to-compare-timestamp-in-where-clause)